# Parsiing DF column having multiple comma separated labels into the individual columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a string column in a Pandas DataFrame having some comma separated labels.

For Example:

```
Row 1: "A, G, Z"
Row 2: "H"
Row 3: "A, H"
```

I need to create one column per label named A, B, C, D …. having 1 in respective row/column if there is that label with the columns name (A,B, ...) in the label string, otherwise set the added column value 0.

So for example above I need to add these columns/values:

```
       A, G, H, Z
Row 1: 1, 1, 0, 1
Row 2: 0, 0, 1, 0
Row 3: 1, 0, 1, 0
```

I thought about iterating over rows, but read in a few places that it will hurt the performance.

I wonder if you could help with ideas how to do that without iterations on rows OR leveraging the iterations in the performance optimized way ...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `pandas.Series.str` does provide a method for this:

#### Solution

```py
# replace `col` with your column name
dummies = df['col'].str.get_dummies(sep=',')

# assign generated columns to data frame
df[dummies.columns] = dummies
```

#### Optional

And I noticed that you might have blank spaces issue from your given examples, here is the solution to remove blank spaces and then generate the columns:

```py
# replace `col` with your column name
df['col'].str.replace(' ', '').str.get_dummies(sep=',')
```

link: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html